Подключение pyright в NVChad
Всем привет, решил начать пользоваться NVChad`ом в NeoVim, но никак не могу подключить к нему pyright. Повторял действия из этого видео https://youtu.be/4BnVeOUeZxc?si=Sw7OOqm7sc4WOH8J, но pyright даже не отображается в списке LSP серверов (:LSPInfo ). Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Рабочее решение нашел здесь: https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad/discussions/2802. А ниже оставил свои конфиги, с которыми автозаполнение с помощью Pyright работает.
plugins/init.lua, описание плагина для загрузки c помощью lazy:
{
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    config = function()
        require "configs.lspconfig"
    end,
},

chadrc.lua: нужно добавить M.mason, чтобы Pyright установился:
---@type ChadrcConfig
local M = {}

M.base46 = {
  theme = "catppuccin",
}

M.mason = {
  pkgs = {
    "pyright",
    "ruff",
  },
}

return M

configs/lspconfig.lua - файл конфигурации LSP:
-- load defaults i.e lua_lsp
require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").defaults()

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local nvlsp = require "nvchad.configs.lspconfig"

lspconfig.pyright.setup {
  on_attach    = nvlsp.on_attach,
  on_init      = nvlsp.on_init,
  capabilities = nvlsp.capabilities,
  filetypes    = {"python"},
  root_dir = function (fname)
    local root_files = {
      'pyproject.toml',
      'pyrightconfig.json'
    }
    return lspconfig.util.root_pattern(table.unpack(root_files))(fname)
      or lspconfig.util.find_git_ancestor(fname)
      or lspconfig.util.path.dirname(fname)
  end
}

